# Trigger is not getting fired when loading the data into the table through sql loader

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-loader

Sql Loader CTL File:

```
options(
skip = 1,
DIRECT = TRUE
)LOAD DATA
INFILE 'E:\sqlloader\testfile.csv'
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE trg_demo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(
    e_id,
    e_name  
)
```

testfile.csv

```
+-------+--------+
| E_ID  | E_NAME |
+-------+--------+
|     1 | A      |
|     2 | B      |
+-------+--------+
```

TRIGGER:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_trg
BEFORE INSERT
ON trg_demo
FOR EACH ROW
  declare 
flag number;
BEGIN

select count(*) into flag from trg_audit d where trunc(d.modified_date) = trunc(sysdate) ;

if flag < 1 then 
    INSERT INTO trg_audit
    VALUES (trg_audit_sq.nextval, current_timestamp);
    end if ;
END;
```

Expected Output from audit table after trigger is fired

Expected output:

```
+------+---------------+
| A_ID | MODIFIED_DATE |
+------+---------------+
|    1 | 23-12-21      |
+------+---------------+
```

But when I am loading the data through SQL loader trigger is not getting fired and I am not getting any records in `trg_audit` table

Comment: Because  SQL*Loader disables some integrity constraints and all database triggers during the direct data loads similar to your case. Btw, your .csv file is expected to be comma-seperated.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thanks. Your comment gave me the direction to resolve this issue. And issue got resolved.

Comment: Nice to hear, you're welcome